# Encode and Decode using UTF-8 in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm looking for an example demonstrating how I can encode and then decode the same string using UTF-8. Encode and then Decode means I want to implement the methods in 2 areas where one can encode it and another is able to decode it.

I have seen the API but I didn't get much success:

- `stringWithCString:encoding:`
- `stringWithUTF8String:`
- `stringWithCString:(const char *)cString encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc;`

---

**EDITED**
I have the string `øæ-test-2.txt` which I am encoding as follows:

```
char *s = "øæ-test-2.txt";
NSString *enc = [NSString stringWithCString:s encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

but am getting `Ã¸Ã¦-test-2.txt` as output.
Now I want to get back the original string back i.e. `øæ-test-2.txt`

---

**EDITED**
I am getting `Ã¸Ã¦-test-2.txt`  from server and I need `øæ-test-2.txt` by decoding it. I am able to get the output from the link : http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf_decode

Please try to use the link and you will understand my concern.

It would be highly appreciated if anyone can give some hint, tutorial or point me in the right direction.

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To turn an `NSString` object into a UTF8 C-string, use `UTF8String`

```
char *utf8string = [@"A string with ümläuts" UTF8String];
```

To turn a UTF8 C-string into an `NSString` object, use `stringWithUTF8String:` or `initWithUTF8String:`

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:utf8string];
```

Note that `NSString` objects are implemented as UTF-16, so you can't really have a "UTF-8 NSString" (and the encoding should be treated as an implementation detail, anyway).

Comment: Well, you can't use NSASCIIStringEncoding to read a UTF-8 string (UTF-8 is not ASCII). Use NSUTF8StringEncoding or the (equivalent but shorter) stringWithUTF8String:

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree that I should not do any ASCII encoding. But I am getting the response as "Ã¸Ã¦-test-2.txt" from the server. I just need to somehow convert it to "øæ-test-2.txt". If I try to UTF-decode ("Ã¸Ã¦-test-2.txt") with below link I am getting  "øæ-test-2.txt". http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf_decode Waiting for your reply

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
char *utf8string = [@"A string with ümläuts" UTF8String];
```

This should be

```
const char *utf8string = [@"A string with ümläuts" UTF8String];
```

Otherwise you have an incompatible type issue.